# Troubleshooting a dynamic SQL query

Tags: php, mysql

anyone can help me what is wrong in my query?

query without error:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE s_id=$id ORDER BY id DESC
```

query with error :

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE s_id=$id AND position=$position ORDER BY id DESC
```

i want to output a data on my database where id and position = inputted id and position

thanks in advance

Comment: Can you provide the code where you make this request?

Comment: Are you getting an error from the code or it is just that the result isn't as expected? The more details you give in the question, more are the chances of you getting your answer here.

Comment: SELECT * FROM table WHERE s_id=$id ORDER BY id DESC
this query is working, but when i do
SELECT * FROM table WHERE s_id=$id AND position=$position ORDER BY id DESC
it does not output anything

sorry im newbie here in stackoverflow

Comment: Well, perhaps that `$position` doesn't exist to that `$id`

Comment: @luceos it does not output anything, btw problem solved thanks anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it that the position column is of varchar type. In that case, you might have to put quotes around $position value.

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE s_id=$id AND position='$position' ORDER BY id DESC
```

Comment: you're very welcome. If it had been the condition that wan't being satisfied, you wouldn't have got the error. It was a syntax error that you were getting. Try posting code and error details while asking a question in future as that would help others understand the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think you both conditions are not true . first you can check with OR Conditions .